# Plink is not accepting sudo password with dollar sign using echo

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

My Plink command is connecting successfully to the server using below command

plink -ssh -no-antispoof USERNAME@SERVERNAME -pw HQ$tbHuvlk -t

but when uses below command foe sudo its  not working. My password contains special character

plink -ssh -no-antispoof USERNAME@SERVERNAME -pw HQ$tbHuvlk -t "echo HQ$tbHuvlk | sudo -S /path/to/shellscript/test.sh;"

Comment: Use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` or escape the `$` with a backslash ``\`` (`\$`)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks later on a day i found solution as same. Thanks it works.
plink -ssh -no-antispoof USERNAME@SERVERNAME -pw HQ$tbHuvlk -t "echo HQ\$tbHuvlk | sudo -S /path/to/shellscript/test.sh;"

Comment: @DavidPostill I have a issue like my script prompts to type Yes or No after sudo password prompt. So my question is if we have some way to pass two echo back to back How can I do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a new question please.

Comment: Thanks for this questions answer... It works for me